# Cal-Heatmap display only 3 months in row another 3 months another row till all 12 months

Tags: jquery, d3.js, cal-heatmap

Hi all I'm using d3js and cal-Heatmap for calendar view in my project, I'm able to  get the examples working.

It provides only **verticalOrientation = false/true** option, but my requirement is that I have to display

```
horizontalOrientation (i.e verticalOrientation = false)
```

But I want 3 months in a row and another 3 months in a row so on.. till all 12 months. please help me in achieving it.

Output goal:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you can use a combination of `subDomain` and `rowLimit`:

```
  var cal = new CalHeatMap();
  cal.init({
    domain: "year",
    subDomain: "x_month",
    rowLimit: 3
  });
```

Full example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="d3@3.5.3" data-semver="3.5.3" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.3/d3.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawgit.com/wa0x6e/cal-heatmap/master/cal-heatmap.css" />
  <script src="https://rawgit.com/wa0x6e/cal-heatmap/master/cal-heatmap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="cal-heatmap"></div>
  <script>
    var cal = new CalHeatMap();
    cal.init({
      domain: "year",
      subDomain: "x_month",
      rowLimit: 3
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi Mark thanks for giving the update
My Requirement is to display the all the 12 months in 4 rows
like
Jan Feb March 
April May June
July August September
October November December
like this i need all the months in 3 columns and 4 rows but all those months are displaying in single row now

Comment: I need out put like this.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/dufclcx59ksa9us/image.png?dl=0